# SP 2013: Use custom managed property for Search Result title of property if it is populated

Tags: 2013, search, search-results, managed-property

In SharePoint 2013, is there a simple way to use a custom managed property for the search result title of property if it is populated? I have several content sources and only 1 of them populates a custom managed property (via a content enrichment service) that I would like used as the title for each search result from that content source.

I thought initially I would be able to go into the Search Schema, add the managed property in to "Mappings to crawled properties" and move it to the top so it would used - but this list only allows crawled properties, not managed properties.

Is there a way to do this - looking online I may need to edit/create an item display template but wondered if there was another way?

Thanks in advance for any advice,

Answer (score 1):

If it was a crawled property it would be easy. Just map it to Title. Since you are using Content Enrichment you can use your service to Update the Title Managed Property rather than (or in addition to) the custom property.

Alternatively, you can create a Display Template and Result Type rule for your result then just edit the template to use your new Managed Property rather than title.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I've given this a try today using a pretty standard content enrichment call and I get some interesting results. It doesn't seem to show any errors in any logs, the managed properties get updated but it never seems to change the title crawled property. I did some searching and I can't seem to find a definitive answer or example as to whether content enrichment changes crawled properties - they all seem to point to managed properties. Do you know if content enrichment changes crawled properties, or does the update just get ignored?  Thanks again

Comment: Content Enrichment work with Managed Properties, not crawled properties. So you would need to adjust your connection to pass Title and update your code to update the Title field.